# React Live Search Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make search input for movies and I need to make it a live search.
Its needs to be triggered after one second and after the user enters 3 characters.
How can I make it with a functional component?

Comment: Please share some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom hook you can do that in the following way:
[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-axios-rickmorty-search-ui-sd2mv?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  useAsyncCallback,
  E_REASON_UNMOUNTED,
  CanceledError
} from "use-async-effect2";
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = useAsyncCallback(
    function* (event) {
      const { value } = event.target;
      if (value.length < 3) return;
      yield CPromise.delay(1000);
      setText("searching...");
      try {
        const response = yield cpAxios(
          `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${value}`
        ).timeout(props.timeout);
        setText(response.data?.results?.map(({ name }) => name).join(","));
      } catch (err) {
        CanceledError.rethrow(err, E_REASON_UNMOUNTED);
        setText(err.response?.status === 404 ? "Not found" : err.toString());
      }
    },
    { cancelPrevious: true }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">
        useAsyncCallback demo: Rickandmortyapi universe character search
      </div>
      Character name: <input onChange={handleSearch}></input>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={handleSearch.cancel}>
        Cancel request
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code already handles the cancellation of the previous search sequence (including aborting the request) and canceling the sequence when the component is unmounted to avoid the React leak warning.